# How to incorporate error message in the program below?

Tags: java

I'm an beginner IT11 student and we're supposed to make a program that will read in the number of the day, the month, and the year a person was born.

For example, someone born on September 3, 1982, would enter the numbers

3, 9, and 1982

into three separate `JOP.showInputDialogs`.

If an incorrect value is entered, the program should give a very specific error message explaining why it is invalid and ask the user to enter the information again. A user should never have to reenter more than one of the values when an invalid entry is made (example, if the day is invalid, the user should only have to reenter the day, not the month or the year).

The program will then tell the person their birthdate with the following format:

You were born September 3, 1982.

The format of the date must be as shown above.

Important
- The program MUST do error checking for invalid months (valid between 1 and 12)
- The program MUST do error checking for invalid years (valid >= 1800)
- The program MUST do error checking for invalid day of month (valid between 1 and maxDay in month (30, 31, 28 or 29))
- The program MUST only allow Feb 29 on LEAP YEARS only.

The part I'm stuck on is incorporating an error message for invalid dates. For example, if I were to input April 31, the program should return an error message saying "April only has 30 days", etc. How do I do that? Here is what I've got so far.

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class A6DateProgram {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year = getYearFromUser();  //gets user input for year
    int month = getMonthFromUser();  //gets user input for month
    int day = getDateFromUser(month, year);  //gets user input for date


    //tells the user their birthdate
    System.out.println("You were born " + Months(month) + " " + day + ", "+ year + " " + ".");
}  //main

//asks user for year 
public static int getYearFromUser(){
    String year; //asks user for year
    int year1 = 0;
    String errorMessage = "";
    boolean isLeap = false;

    do{
        year = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(errorMessage +  "Please enter the year you were born in. (>1800)");

        if (year == null) {
        System.out.println("You clicked cancel");
        System.exit(0);
        } 

        // parse string to an int
        try {
            year1 = Integer.parseInt(year);  //parses recieved number to an int
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorMessage = "Invalid integer\n";  //if user does not input valid integer
            continue;  //continues to condition [while(true);]
        } // catch

        isLeap = validateYear(year1);

        if(year1 < 1800 || year1 > 2400){  //number limitation
            errorMessage = "Your number must be greater than 1800 or less than 2400. \n"; //if user does not input a valid integer between limit
            continue;  //continues to condition [while(true);]
        }
            break;
        } while(true);
          return year1;
  } //getYearFromUser

public static boolean validateYear(int year){
return (year % 400 == 0 ) ? true : (year%100 == 0)? false : (year % 4 == 0)? true: false;
}
//asks user for month
public static int getMonthFromUser(){
    String month;
    int num = 0;
    String errorMessage = "";

    do{
        month = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(errorMessage +  "Please enter the month you were born in as a valid integer. (ex. January = 1)");

        if (month == null) {
        System.out.println("You clicked cancel");
        System.exit(0);
        }

        // parse string to an int
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(month);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorMessage = "Invalid integer\n";
            continue;  //continues to condition [while(true);]
        } // catch

        if(num > 12 || num < 1){
            errorMessage = "A year only has 12 months. \n";
            continue;  //continues to condition [while(true);]
        }
            break;
        } while(true);
          return num;
        } //getMonthFromUser


//asks user for date
public static int getDateFromUser(int month, int year){
    String date;
    int day = 0;
    String errorMessage = "";
    boolean ToF = false;

    do{
        date = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(errorMessage +  "Please enter the date you were born in. (1-31)");

        //user clicks cancel
        if (date == null) {
        System.out.println("You clicked cancel");
        System.exit(0);
        }
        // parse string to an int
        try {
            day = Integer.parseInt(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorMessage = "Invalid integer\n";
            continue;  //continues to condition [while(true);]
        } // catch

         ToF = validate(year, month, day); //giving boolean ToF a method to validate the day

         if(ToF == false){
            errorMessage = "The month you input does not have that date. \n";
            continue;  //continues to condition [while(true);]
        }
        break;

    } while(true);  //do
     return day;
}    //getDateFromUser

public static boolean validate(int year, int month, int day){
switch(month){
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 10:
    case 12:
        if(day < 1 || day > 31)
            return false;
        break;
    case 2:
        if(year%4 == 0 || (year%400 == 0 && year%100 != 0)){
            if (day < 1 || day > 29)
                return false;
        }else{
            if (day < 1 || day > 28)
                return false;
        }
        break;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        if(day < 1 || day > 30)
            return false;
        break;
}

return true;
}   //validate

//resonse to user input for month
public static String Months(int month) {
switch (month) {
case 1: return "January";
case 2: return "Febrary";
case 3: return "March";
case 4: return "April";
case 5: return "May";
case 6: return "June";
case 7: return "July";
case 8: return "August";
case 9: return "September";
case 10: return "October";
case 11: return "November";
case 12: return "December";

    default: return "Invalid";
    } // switch
} //Months
} //A6DateProgram Class
```

Comment: What if the user wanted to enter 30th march and enters 30th feb instead?. Will you force him to change the date from 30th to something  below 29?

Comment: The program would force him to change the date to a valid one.

Comment: "If an incorrect value is entered, the program should give a very specific error message explaining why it is invalid and ask the user to enter the information again. A user should never have to reenter more than one of the values when an invalid entry is made (example, if the day is invalid, the user should only have to reenter the day, not the month or the year)." . My question is how will you determine whether the day is invalid or the month from my previous example?

Comment: It would be the date that's invalid.

Comment: Like i said.. I wanted to enter march.. I entered Feb - "by mistake". Now, you will ask me to change the date?

Comment: Then you would click cancel & start over. This is our first major project in this class & we haven't learned to go back and stuff so the date's the one that would have to be changed if there were an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `SimpleDateFormat()`

```
String date  = "3";
String month = "9";
String year  = "1980";
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
Date date1 = sdf1.parse((Integer.parseInt(date)<10?"0"+date:date)+(Integer.parseInt(month)<10?"0"+month:month)+year);
String ansStr = sdf2.format(date1);
System.out.println("You were born "+ansStr);
```

If you enter an invail date it automatically take the next date.

Eaxmple if the input is `29-02-2014` it will take as `01-03-2014`